# Add key to unique values in the SQl database

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL data looks like this:

```
Col1
A
A
A
B
B
C
D
```

I want to add a key to only unique values. So the end result will look like this:

```
Col1  Col2
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       2
B       2
C       3
D       3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `dense_rank()` window function:

```
select col1, dense_rank() over (order by col1) as col2
from t;
```

This solves the problem as a query.  If you want to actually change the table, then the code is more like:

```
alter table t add col2 int;

with toupdate as (
    select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by col1) as newcol2
    from t
)
update toupdate
    set col2 = newcol2;
```

Comment: @Randy . . . `rownum` is not a SQL Server construct.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the second part to work. What I did instead was to just SELECT * INTO newTable FROM dense_rank query.

Comment: @user2343837 . . . Here is an example of it working in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17837/1).  But, `select into` also works.